# detect that a command line window is scroll-locked

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-console, win32-process

Scenario:

A long wait for an automated test run lies ahead....  I might as well go have lunch.  So I lock my workstation, go enjoy my sandwiches and return after an hour, confident that by now, I'm going to have the test results alright.

Not so... Since I marked a line of text in the CMD prompt terminal, it's stdout was blocked, and the tests got blocked on it, too....

So here's my question:

Is there an API to detect "any console window" that have their standard output blocked?

Comment: What are you going to do with the result?

Comment: @EricBrown: pop-up a message when I lock my workstation.  And hope that I notice it :)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such Win32 function. But you can:

*Disable QuickEdit.*

Right click title bar of the console window. Go to properties and uncheck QuickEdit Mode.

*Or* create a tool which detects if a console window has a window title that starts with "Select" and send it a keypress or mousepress to unblock it.